# Calculate system CPU usage for console application running on IoT Core

Tags: c#, docker, console-application, cpu-usage, windows-10-iot-core

I am referring below link to calculate cpu usage on win iot core-

[Calculate CPU Usage in Percentage UWP Application Windows 10 IOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009567/calculate-cpu-usage-in-percentage-uwp-application-windows-10-iot)

But it require Windows.System.Diagnostics to access for below code snippet to get info for running process-

```
    var pdis = ProcessDiagnosticInfo.GetForProcesses();
```

But i am not able to find nuget package for ProcessDiagnosticInfo C# console application.

Is there any way to calcualte cpu usage on iot core.

Comment: PerformanceCounter doesn't have support on IoT Core. It is working on Windows 10 Enterprise and have tested this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too fast, I have to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **PerformanceCounter** doesn't have support on IoT Core. If you want to get the CPU usage of the system in console application on Windows IoT Core, you can call the Device Portal API([/api/resourcemanager/processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core#performance-data)) to get the system performance data.

Comment: I can use device portal api but credentials is required to access that. That's why don't want to go with solution. I am running application in docker container and there are some security restrictions.

Comment: Can you create a UWP app to run in the docker module?

Comment: I am running Microsoft azure edge based solution in docker container. running UWP app on top of that will be a problem.

Comment: So it is better to run a UWP outside the docker container to monitor the OS performance.