# UWP how to properly calculate Total CPU Utilization

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp

just wanted to ask a question that was asked around the StackOverflow a few times, and I tried all of the examples, but I cannot get it right.

I am trying to calc a CPU Utilization in a UWP application like this:

```
    Dim oldcpu = SystemDiagnosticInfo.GetForCurrentSystem().CpuUsage.GetReport()
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait()
    Dim newcpu = SystemDiagnosticInfo.GetForCurrentSystem().CpuUsage.GetReport()
    Dim cpuUsageTotal = ((newcpu.KernelTime - oldcpu.KernelTime) + (newcpu.UserTime - oldcpu.UserTime)) / TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000) / ProcessorCount * 100
    Debug.WriteLine(cpuUsageTotal)
```

I probably tried 100 different scenarios, for example adding or removing delta IdleTime from the equation, I also tried the approach with Stopwatch, and basically all suggestions I could find all over the internet.
But no luck the values I get are not close to what's showing in the Task Manager.

any help?

Thank you

Comment: How much is the difference from the value of Task Manager？And what's the `ProcessorCount`  in your environment ?

Comment: Proc Count is 4 - 12 tested on multiple physical and virtual machines. 
if Task Manager shows 12 % for example my app shows 5% or 1% (not consistent)

Comment: Subtracting IdleTime doesn't make sense.  CPU usage is amount of time working divided by amount of time elapsed.  So 100.0 * (KernelTime + UserTime) / (KernelTime + UserTime + IdleTime)

Comment: Thanks, Hans, i saw this implementation in the other post, but it does not work
so I have : 
100 * ((newcpu.KernelTime - oldcpu.KernelTime) + (newcpu.UserTime - oldcpu.UserTime)) / ((newcpu.KernelTime - oldcpu.KernelTime) + (newcpu.UserTime - oldcpu.UserTime) + (newcpu.IdleTime - oldcpu.IdleTime))
I get : 
50
50.0963391136802
50.2901353965184
50
50.0963391136802
50
51.792828685259
51.4851485148515

Comment: Have you tried get report with ProcessDiagnosticInfo, please refer to this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040163/7254781)

Comment: Nico ProcessDiagnosticInfo will only provide info for the current process and not for all processes on the system, even if the package is set "fullTrust", that is why I thought that SystemDiagnosticInfo.GetForCurrentSystem().CpuUsage.GetReport()  would work but after trying multiple different formulas, noting work :( so far no luck

Comment: May be you need add packageQuery appDiagnostics  capability to access other process.

Comment: Tried, no luck, but also my question is specifically to SystemDiagnosticInfo.GetForCurrentSystem().CpuUsage.GetReport()

Comment: You could also use get cpu usage within desktop extension and pass the data to UWP client by desktop bridge.